# cannot execute npm run env:restart

Tags: typescript, hyperledger, convector, hurley

I am trying to run a simple example here, so far I have setup the convector workspace by installing `convector-cli` and `hurley`, also did the npm install. When I try to run the `npm run env:restart` I get the following error stack trace.

```
Error: No such container: peer0.org1.hurley.lab
Error: No such container: peer0.org1.hurley.lab
Joining ch1 channel on peer peer0.org1.hurley.lab
++ docker exec peer0.org1.hurley.lab peer channel join -b /shared/ch1.block
Error: No such container: peer0.org1.hurley.lab
++ echo fail
+ output=fail
+ set +x
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your container Name

https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1297#issuecomment-441506890

first Go into your `~/.lando` folder, delete any files or folders named the same as the one that was giving you an error, then build again.